# Understanding this sensing approach

Tags: current-measurement

What could be the intent of the designer who made this? As far as I understand, if Vcc = 35V, when MOSFET is ON, actuator_sense pin goes to zero. When the MOSFET is OFF, the resistance L1 and R25 are in parallel. So by resistor divider formula, we get a voltage across R27, or actuator_sense pin. I think the designer only wants to know if L1 is present or not? Right?

[image]

Comment: think `Q1 failure / gate pulse failure`

Comment: And L1 open circuit failure.

Answer (score 0):

if q1 closed, coil not engaged an output "sense" would be 35V * (5.9/100) = 2V
if L1 burn "sense" 35V * (5.9/(100+100) ) = 1V
if Q1 open "sense" = 0V

Comment: For first case, Q1 is open, not closed.

Comment: Sense = 0 for Q1 short, not open.

Comment: yep,  mess it up :)